# Interfaces and abstract class attributes in C++

Tags: c++

I have an "interface", called `Base`, defined as follows:

```
struct Base {
    int number(){
        return 17;
    };
};
```

Now a `Derived` class implements the method `number`.

```
struct Derived: Base {
    int number() {
        return 42;
    }
};
```

Finally, some other object will use any class derived from `Base`.

```
struct Other {
    Base b;
    Other(Base b): b(b) {
        cout << b.number() << endl;
    }
};
```

The problem is that when constructing `Other` with a `Derived` class, the method `number` is called from the base class. The following prints '17' instead of '42'.

```
Derived d;
Other o(d);
```

How can this be fixed?

*Remark.* I learned OOP in Java; c++ is new to me.

Comment: Which C++ textbook are you learning from? C++ is really nothing like Java and you are not going to learn it by asking questions about the very basics of the language here.

Comment: @Neil Accelerated C++. Thanks for your insightful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should mark `number()` `virtual` and override it in `Derived`:

```
struct Base {
    virtual int number(){
        return 17;
    };
};
```

But this doesn't yet fix the problem. In your `Other` struct the member `b` is an object of type `Base`, because it's an object (and not a pointer/reference) any derivee you pass will be sliced to just a mere `Base` object. What you should do instead is save that information in a pointer or reference:

```
struct Other {
    Base* b;
    Other(Base* b): b(b) {
        cout << b->number() << endl;
    }
};
```

And:

```
Derived d;
Other o(&d);
```

Beware for dangling pointers with this setup.

Comment: @M(r/s)GrumpyDownvoter a comment would be nice so I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your function virtual and pass a reference or a pointer to Base in your Other class.

Comment: Yes Base, which implies it'll be virtual in Derived as well, of course.